# How to store leftover fermenting wine for reuse later?

Tags: fermentation, techniques, wine, first-time-brewer

I've got a decent amount of leftover wine (ginger) after racking from my primary to a couple of demijohns. I want to use this for the topping up when I eventually rerack in a few months' time but I'm not sure how to store it. It's currently in a normal wine bottle (using about 650 of its 750ml) but I don't have an air lock that fits it though I've heard you can get away with just putting some muslin wrap over the opening.

My question ultimately is can I leave this leftover in the bottle with some muslin wrapped over it and then use it top up my demijohns when I'm reracking? Or should I just drink it right now as it tastes delicious (probably due to the unfermented sugar that remains... SG of 1046) and top up as normal with water/syrup when necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can. In fact this is what Jack Keller recommends. It is a second (or third in your case) fermentation to keep clean. Make sure you taste it first. A growler will get you a 1/2 gallon. You can use a drilled rubber stopper to add an airlock.

Comment: I kept it for about a month with just the muslin and it seemed fine when I used it top up one of my demijohns - made sure to keep one of them free from it just in case it goes tits up!